# What is the purpose of ServletContext setInitParameter? How can one use it?

Tags: java, servlets

The Servlet 3.0 Specification says:

```
setInitParameter

boolean setInitParameter(java.lang.String name,
                         java.lang.String value)

    Sets the context initialization parameter with the given name and value on this ServletContext.

    Parameters:
        name - the name of the context initialization parameter to set
        value - the value of the context initialization parameter to set 
    Returns:
        true if the context initialization parameter with the given name and value was set successfully on this ServletContext, and false if it was not set because this ServletContext already contains a context initialization parameter with a matching name 
    Throws:
        IllegalStateException - if this ServletContext has already been initialized 
        UnsupportedOperationException - if this ServletContext was passed to the ServletContextListener#contextInitialized method of a ServletContextListener that was neither declared in web.xml or web-fragment.xml, nor annotated with WebListener
    Since:
        Servlet 3.0
```

As I understand, a servlet context is initialized when a web application is deployed. When I say, `servletConfig.getServletContext().setInitParameter("email", "foo@bar.com")` inside a servlets doGet() I am getting `IllegalStateException.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in the javadoc, the exception is thrown if you try to call the method after the `ServletContext` has been initialized

> IllegalStateException - if this ServletContext has already been initialized

In pre 3.0 Servlet applications, you could set context parameters with the following configuration

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>some-param</param-name>
    <param-value>some-value</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This would set a context wide parameter which any Servlet application component can access.

Since 3.0, you can move your deployment configuration to Java code. Typically you would implement the [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html) interface. The Servlet container would find your implementation, instantiate it and execute its [`onStartup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html#onStartup%28java.util.Set,%20javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) method handing you the uninitialized `ServletContext`.

You could then use the `setInitParameter` method to set context parameters like you would have done in the deployment descriptor. When your `onStartup()` method returns, the Servlet container does further processing to set up the web application. When it is done, it initializes the `ServletContext` and your application is ready to go and handle requests.